# (WFP)how can I drop data in FWPM_LAYER_STREAM_V4 layer

Tags: python, windows, driver, wfp

my program includes an exe and a sys.
The sys works in FWPM_LAYER_STREAM_V4 layer of WFP, when sys catch stream data, it will pass the data to the exe, then the exe will check whether the data is forbidden.
When in classifyfn I block the data though following code for further check:

```
    FWPS_STREAM_CALLOUT_IO_PACKET0* pPackInfo = (FWPS_STREAM_CALLOUT_IO_PACKET0*)layerData;
    pIoPacket->streamAction = FWPS_STREAM_ACTION_NONE;
    classifyOut->actionType = FWP_ACTION_BLOCK;
```

Then sys will wait for the exe result in a Specific thread.
if the data is not forbidden,then I will inject the data back to the flow.otherwise I want to drop the data. But I really don't know how to drop the data,so how can I drop the data in `FWPM_LAYER_STREAM_V4` layer?

Answer (score 1):

to drop the stream you only have to block it, you have to return FWP_ACTION_BLOCK with the FWPS_CLASSIFY_OUT_FLAG_ABSORB bit set.